# Read Pre defined Style in MapinfoTab File in Geotools

Tags: java, ogr2ogr, geotools

We have open a `MapInfoTab File` using `OGRFeatureSource` the file open on map successfully. But one question we have there is a function named `GetStyleString` in `OGRLibrary` of `Ogr2Ogr` but in our `OGRSource` the same method is not present. How we can override the same method.
And one more thing if we have a `Style` feature wise means each feature has a different style is there any option to open style feature wise without creating a `Rule`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could get the MapInfo style string out of the file it has no real value to GeoTools (at present).

If you want to style each feature differently the only way to do it is to construct an SLD object based on properties (attributes) of the features to control the styling, possibly with additional filtering (or judicious use of the if-then-else function).

Comment: thanks for this , but one more thing there is an explanation for all the functions in `BridgeOgr` in class `OgrLibrary.java` . What is the equivalent of all those methods present in that Class  and how they load style on map?